# bootstrap alignment issue with sidebar and content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

[image: view of side bar closed state]I am learning the bootstrap and I have tried to create simple page with sidebar.

My live demo is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-sidebar)

In this example when the sidebar is closed the content part not taking full widh of the display. any  one guide me to fix this. I want content part should not be overflow out of the screen size when side bar is opened and occupy full width when side bar is closed.

[image: View of side bar opened state]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply one CSS rule and need to change the `container` to `container-fluid`

Following is the CSS rule in your `style.css`:

```
#content {
   width: 100vw;
}
```

Note:- if you fine with container's left and right spaces then do not change it to container-fluid.

Hope this will work you :)